# Bootstrap 4 and issues with the 'collapse' function

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues with the collapse function in Bootstrap. A lot of other posts addressing this issue suggest that one should make sure that jQuery is above bootstrap. I've taken care to do this, but the error `$(...).collapse is not a function` persists:

```
<head>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  

<!-- popper for tooltips -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js">

<!-- bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- chart.js for data visualization -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>



</head>
```

Other bootstrap functionality works perfectly fine. Any ideas on how I can address this? Am I perhaps using an outdated form of jQuery?

Comment: Where you connecting bootstrap.min.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Mate you are missing JS bundle for Bootstrap. You need to actually add a plugin in order to be able to call it.

```
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Remember to ensure you call it on the jQuery object.

```
const iWillWork = $('.el')
const iWillNotWork = document.querySelectorAll('.el')

iWillWork.collapse()
iWillNotWork.collapse() // Collapse is not a fucntion...
```

If it's not the case please add more details to your question.

Comment: this worked! Thank you so much, I figured I was missing something, I feel slightly sheepish now but I'm also relieved

Comment: which part do you mean? The missing js bundle or the way you call it? I am glad I could help :)

Comment: The missing js bundle - I was using the correct syntax to call the function :)